# Bootstrap grid not rendering properly on mobile devices

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following bootsrap grid on my site. It works well for large and medium screen sizes but on a mobile/smaller screen I'm only seeing 1 item - basically all the columns are stacked on smaller screens. It's like the browser is not respecting the "col-xs-6" class in the column.

Any ideas of how I can troubleshoot this? I've tried to look at inspector but I'm pretty lost.

I'm using a [Bootswatch v5.1.1 template called Darkly](https://bootswatch.com/darkly/) if that makes any difference.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>new and trending</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace the `col-xs-6` with `col-6`. There is no `col-xs-` in Bootstrap 5. [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Oh my I feel stupid. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

According to bootstrap documentation. XS means Extra Small Devices. For testing xs grid you have to test with device width 576px or less than(<576px). And finally you have to write just ***col*** not ***col-xs***. Change your code

change your code to-

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>new and trending</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can visit [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. The answer was that col-xs is not supported in Bootstrap 4/5 so thats why it wasnt working

Comment: Thanks you very much. If it is helpful for you, Please accept my answer to spread everyone. And Please vote me.